# SugerCRM Warning: Creating default object from empty value

Tags: editor

when i am trying to edit field from sugerCRM editor then i am getting this issue.
even i try to use this patch as well as a solution for this error but still getting this issue.

```
https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/pull/143

( ! ) Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\trunk\modules\ModuleBuilder\views\view.modulefield.php on line 151
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks friend but this issue is being resolved we just need to replace line number 151 in view.modulefield.php file with

```
if(!isset($module->mbvardefs) || is_null($module->mbvardefs)) {
    $module->mbvardefs = new stdClass();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the other answer almost correct but it generated further warnings, this seemed to solve them completely for me:

```
if(!isset($module->mbvardefs) || is_null($module->mbvardefs)) {
    $module->mbvardefs = new stdClass();
}
$module->mbvardefs->vardefs =  $dictionary[$objectName];
```

It is kind of frustrating that SugarCRM comes with bugs like this when using modern versions of PHP..

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work for me, I found that the inserted statement needed to come AFTER the original problem line instead of before it, but big thanks for the solution.  This has solved a big headache for me that no-one else seems to have had a pill for!